# Keras ValueError: expected input to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (16,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have written the following code, and are trying to predict an image from an variational autoencoder model:

Encoder:

```
input_img = Input(shape=(28, 28, 3))

x = Conv2D(32, 3,
                  padding='same', 
                  activation='relu')(input_img)
x = Conv2D(64, 3,
                  padding='same', 
                  activation='relu',
                  strides=(2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(64, 3,
                  padding='same', 
                  activation='relu')(x)
x = Conv2D(64, 3,
                  padding='same', 
                  activation='relu')(x)

x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(16, activation='relu')(x)

# Two outputs, latent mean and (log)variance
z_mu = Dense(latent_dim)(x)
z_log_sigma = Dense(latent_dim)(x)

encoder = Model(inputs = input_img, outputs = x)
```

Decoder:

```
# decoder takes the latent distribution sample as input
decoder_input = Input(K.int_shape(z)[1:])

# Expand to 784 total pixels
x = Dense(np.prod(shape_before_flattening[1:]),
                 activation='relu')(decoder_input)

# reshape
x = Reshape(shape_before_flattening[1:])(x)

# use Conv2DTranspose to reverse the conv layers 
x = Conv2DTranspose(32, 3,
                           padding='same', 
                           activation='relu',
                           strides=(2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(3, 3,
                  padding='same', 
                  activation='sigmoid')(x)

# decoder model statement
decoder = Model(decoder_input, x)

# apply the decoder to the sample from the latent distribution
z_decoded = decoder(z)
```

The encoder looks like this:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_13 (InputLayer)        (None, 28, 28, 3)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 32)        896       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 14, 14, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 14, 14, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 14, 14, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 12544)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_10 (Dense)             (None, 16)                200720    
=================================================================
Total params: 293,968
Trainable params: 293,968
Non-trainable params: 0
```

and the decoder as such:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_15 (InputLayer)        (None, 2)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_14 (Dense)             (None, 12544)             37632     
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_3 (Reshape)          (None, 14, 14, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_2 (Conv2DTr (None, 28, 28, 32)        18464     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 3)         867       
=================================================================
Total params: 56,963
Trainable params: 56,963
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

It runs very well. Here is the complete model:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_13 (InputLayer)           (None, 28, 28, 3)    0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 28, 28, 32)   896         input_13[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (None, 14, 14, 64)   18496       conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)               (None, 14, 14, 64)   36928       conv2d_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)               (None, 14, 14, 64)   36928       conv2d_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)             (None, 12544)        0           conv2d_4[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_10 (Dense)                (None, 16)           200720      flatten_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_11 (Dense)                (None, 2)            34          dense_10[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_12 (Dense)                (None, 2)            34          dense_10[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_5 (Lambda)               (None, 2)            0           dense_11[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_12[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
model_16 (Model)                (None, 28, 28, 3)    56963       lambda_5[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
custom_variational_layer_3 (Cus [(None, 28, 28, 3),  0           input_13[0][0]                   
                                                                 model_16[1][0]                   
==================================================================================================
Total params: 350,999
Trainable params: 350,999
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

The issue is when I am trying to create an image based on an existing image. This shows an image from the training-set:

```
rnd_file = np.random.choice(files)
file_id = os.path.basename(rnd_file)
img = imread(rnd_file)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Then, I add the image to the encoder to get a latent representation of the image:

```
z = encoder.predict(img)
```

Whei I have the latent representation, I decode it based on the given representation into an image:

```
decoder.predict(z)
```

That gives the following error:

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_15 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (16,)

z looks like this:

```
[0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.03668813
 0.10211123 0.08731555 0.         0.01327576 0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.03561973 0.02009114]
```

The output of the encoder is (None, 16), as is the same as my z. And it runs as a model. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Some code is missing to understand exactly what you want to achieve, but there are at least two issues:

- In this example, the size of z is not `(None, 16)` but `(16,)`. You need to add a dimension, for example like this: `z = encoder.predict(img[np.newaxis, :])`
- The input size of your decoder does not match the output size of your encoder

Comment: It works fine for the encoder. It is when I try the decoder, it gives the issue. If I try decoder.predict(z[np.newaxis, :]) I get ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_43 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 16, 16)

Comment: The encoder takes a batch of 28x28x3 images as input and returns a batch of tensors of dimension16. The decoder has inputs of dimension 2 and therefore cannot take the output of the encoder as its input. Are you sure about the encoder model definition?
In your code for the decoder on the 2nd line, z is not defined but probably doesn't match the encoder output.

Answer (score 0):

the error message suggest to me that it was expecting a tuple of length 2.

eg in this intro article:

https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html

they do this:

```
    output_tokens, h, c = decoder_model.predict(
        [target_seq] + states_value)
```

your code just passes the `target_seq` but not the `states_value`, which looks to me why you are getting that error.